# Eclipse not getting Launched showing error -The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers and my java version is java version "1.8.0_131" .
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit) and the JDK version is 1.8.
 The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized. Will retry after the state location is initialized. Segmentation fault (core dumped) -This is the errror i am getting !!

Answer (score 0):

i was getting a similar error when i was trying to run eclipse mars with java 8.  Switching to java 7 solved it.