# Running eclipse using docker

Tags: eclipse, docker, user-interface

I have been assigned a project to install tomcat9, spring-5.7 and eclipse in a docker and create a docker image.

---

The following is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install apt-utils sudo -y

# INSTALL UTILITIES WGET AND TAR
RUN apt-get install wget tar -y

# INSTALL MAVEN GRADLE AND JDK
RUN apt-get install maven gradle default-jdk -y

# INSTALL ECLIPSE
RUN wget http://mirror.tspu.ru/eclipse/technology/epp/downloads/release/2020-06/R/eclipse-jee-2020-06-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz -P /opt
RUN cd /opt && tar xvzf eclipse-jee-2020-06-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

# INSTALL TOMCAT
RUN apt-get install tomcat9 -y
EXPOSE 8080

# INSTALL SPRING LIBRARIES
RUN mkdir "/usr/local/spring-v5.2.7"
RUN wget "https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-5.2.7.RELEASE-dist.zip" -P "/usr/local/spring-v5.2.7/"
RUN unzip "/usr/local/spring-v5.2.7/spring-5.2.7.RELEASE-dist.zip"

# INSTALL GEDIT
RUN apt-get install gedit -y

ENTRYPOINT /opt/eclipse/eclipse
```

(Its still under development, as you can see from the fact that tomcat has just been installed and not started)

---

Now, this is the command I am using to run the container:

```
docker container run --rm --net=host -it --env=DISPLAY --volume=$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw microservices-docker
```

---

A weird thing is that my eclipse gives [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777225/eclipse-not-getting-launched-showing-error-the-org-eclipse-m2e-logback-configur) error when the docker has been built WITHOUT gedit, whereas runs smoothly (well, with the normal dbus-errors) when gedit has been added to the image.

---

My question is, what *extra* packages are being installed by gedit, which make the container run smoothly?

Comment: Please add the exact error message to your question. Does installing Gedit change the GTK version ([Eclipse 2020-06 requires GTK 3.20 or higher](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.16/platform_isv.php#gtk-min-version))? The GTK version isthe only thing I can think of that might be changed by installing Gedit and that can affect Eclipse. What is the version before and after `apt-get install gedit -y`?

Comment: As you use very explicit downloads you may want to cache them next to your dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Eclipse 2020-06 (4.16) requires GTK 3.20 or higher](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.16/platform_isv.php#gtk-min-version). I guess, this requirement is fulfilled as a side effect of doing `apt-get install gedit -y`.

As you have found out yourself, you can also install only the following packages instead:

- libgtk-3-0:amd64
- libgtk-3-bin
- libgtk-3-common
- libgtksourceview-3.0-1:amd64
- libgtksourceview-3.0-common

Answer (score 1):

After I had a little chat with @howlger (and after he scolded me a little :P) I found the solution. Installing `gedit` installs

> - libgtk-3-0:amd64
> - libgtk-3-bin
> - libgtk-3-common
> - libgtksourceview-3.0-1:amd64
> - libgtksourceview-3.0-common

Installing these packages separately worked and I got a working eclipse-docker.